# Curl content to be placed in the php array

Tags: php, curl

there is information received through CURL with the content:

```
login=Vasya Pupkin city=Moscow tel=0 123 456 567 sex=male
```

How do I properly break it into an array for further work with the data? At the moment I have this code, so why can not I skip it through foreach: Invalid argument supplied for `foreach()`. I understand this because the information received is not transferred to the array.

```
<?php
function file_get_contents_curl($url) { 
    $ch = curl_init(); 

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Justice.ru");
    $data = iconv('windows-1251', 'UTF-8', $data);
    $data = curl_exec($ch); 
    curl_close($ch); 
    return $data; 
} 

$lines = file_get_contents_curl('http://emeraldscity.combats.ru/inf.pl?short=1327641470');
foreach($lines as $value)
        { 
                list($var, $val) = explode('=',$value); 
                $arr[$var] = $val; 
        }
echo $arr['login'];
?>
```

Comment: You need to transform the info returned from your curl request into array right?

Comment: yeap, thats what i need

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function file_get_contents_curl($url) { 
    $ch = curl_init(); 

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Justice.ru");
    $data = curl_exec($ch); 
    curl_close($ch); 
    $d = json_encode($data);
    return json_decode($d , true); 
} 

$lines = file_get_contents_curl('http://emeraldscity.combats.ru/inf.pl?short=1327641470');
foreach($lines as $value)
        { 
                list($var, $val) = explode('=',$value); 
                $arr[$var] = $val; 
        }
echo $arr[login];
?>
```

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: `return json_decode($d , true)` I've missed a semicolon to this line. I don't know if you've fixed it on the code.

Comment: @ВладМазур Do you tried to `var_dump()` the `$lines`var? I see that it's null, I'm testing your code.

Comment: Try it with return $data;

Comment: I see the output, but it contains a lot of unencoded chars. What kind of data do you expect to be returned from that url?

Comment: $data = iconv('windows-1251', 'UTF-8', $data);

Comment: I need put meanings into variable which after the sign "="

Comment: Excuse me, what do you mean?" = ."

Answer (score 0):

This tough must have a certain style like xml or json or array ..

Answer (score 0):

With file_get_contents_curl you get a string, not an array. So before going through the lines you have to extract them from the string.

```
$content = file_get_contents_curl('http://emeraldscity.combats.ru/inf.pl?short=1327641470');
$lines = explode(PHP_EOL,$content);
foreach ($lines as $value) {
    list($var, $val) = explode('=', $value);
    $arr[$var] = $val;
}
```